# Python websocket: retries while receiving data

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, slack-api

I have task to receive data from Slack API (Events API). I do what needed: create channel, put bot in it, set socketmode in bot settings and subscribe to events. In my code i get url with `apps_connections_open` API method and use websocket python package to connect through it. So i run script, write message in channel and even see the response data in my terminal, but it starts to duplicate: first row with `"retry_attempt":0,"retry_reason":""`, second row with `"retry_attempt":1,"retry_reason":"timeout"`, etc.

[server response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPpTx.png)

Why it starts to do multiple attempts with timeout? I assumed that reason in acknowledge - the server needs to confirm sent data. In Slack doc:

```
Use the envelope_id field in the object you receive from your websocket to send a response back to Slack acknowledging that you've received the event
```

But i can't get that envelope_id value from received dict: second print in `on_message` function did not work (nothing except `print(message)` didn't work). It looks like reason in websocket internals, but i don't understand in what exactly. What is need to stop retries?

```
from settings import slack_app_token
from settings import slack_client
import websocket


def on_open(ws_app):
    print("Connection is opened")


def on_message(ws_app, message):
    print(message)
    envelope_id = message['envelope_id']
    print(f'envelope_id is {envelope_id}')
    ws_app.send(envelope_id)


conn = slack_client.apps_connections_open(app_token=slack_app_token)
url = conn['url']

ws_app = websocket.WebSocketApp(url, on_message=on_message, on_open=on_open)
ws_app.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using other package **[slack_bolt](https://slack.dev/bolt-python/tutorial/getting-started)**.

```
from settings import slack_token, slack_app_token 
from slack_bolt import App 
from slack_bolt.adapter.socket_mode import SocketModeHandler


app = App(token=slack_token)

handler = SocketModeHandler(app, slack_app_token)


@app.event("message") 
def handle_message_events(body):
    print(body)


handler.start()
```